# Microsoft Word Macro Called in SAS

Tags: vba, formatting, sas, ms-office, border

I created a custom Microsoft Word macro called DoubleBorders that does just that -- puts double borders on all tables in the document. The VBA code is:

```
Sub TableNoBorders()
    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        tbl.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
        tbl.Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle 
    Next
End Sub
```

Is it possible to call this code and output tables with double borders as I output an RTF file from SAS?

```
DATA TEST;
    INPUT CAR $12. YEAR;
    DATALINES;
    CHEVY   2001
    FORD    2005
    HONDA   2008
    ;
RUN;

ODS RTF FILE= "C:\Users\Documents\SAS Example Code\Test.rtf" STYLE=STATISTICAL;

** maybe insert code here to call my custom VBA DoubleBorders macro? **;

PROC REPORT DATA = TEST NOWD;
    COLUMN CAR YEAR;
    DEFINE CAR / DISPLAY "Car";
    DEFINE YEAR / DISPLAY "Year";
RUN;

ODS RTF CLOSE;
```

Comment: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi25/25/ad/25p021.pdf

Comment: @TimWilliams Sounds like an answer.